# "How I wish I could calculate pi" analogs...

Tags: soft-question, pi, euler-mascheroni-constant, mnemonic, constants

You might know the mnemonic for $\pi$ in the title or even this more elaborated one:

> Sir, I bear a rhyme excelling
>   In mystic force, and magic spelling
>   Celestial sprites elucidate
>   All my own striving can't relate
>   Or locate they who can cogitate
>   And so finally terminate.
>   Finis.

Are there any for other than $\pi$? Feel free to create your own! 
Here's my try for [$\gamma$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant):

> "0 Euler Leonhard" $\to 0,58$

**Choose your favorite language** and feel free to post a riddle...

Comment: Write the mnemonic first, and define the number to match it :) .

Comment: Doesn't really fall under your category, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDiSYp_51iY) is a pretty cool (and effective!) way of memorizing a lot of $\pi$.

Comment: For bonus points, make those into a Haiku.

Comment: Wikipedia has this info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piphilology

Comment: that's actually quite entertaining... i think this can be somewhat automated in that a program can be made to generate nonsensical sentences that are grammatically correct.

Comment: I'm converting this to CW

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My spirits I brighten by leveling a mountain of decrepit milk maids furiously canoodling with lords of the manor.

Comment: Yes, canoodling is underused.

Comment: +1 nic[e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)

Comment: canoodling has 10 letters?

Comment: @Jonas: Yes: $10\equiv0\pmod{10}$.

Comment: But isn't $9$ missing then?

Comment: @Jonas: Eep! You’re right; I left out a word.

Comment: Nice; I was thinking an adverb would fit, but I wouldn't have thought of as good of one.

Comment: @Jonas: I was just sorry that *wantonly* was too short!

Answer (score 7):

Martin Gardner quoted one for $\pi$ which I like:

How I wish a drink, alcoholic of course, after the heavy chapters involving quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe have a look at:

[*Ivars Peterson's MathTrek*](http://www.maa.org/mathland/mathland_3_11.html)

[*Pi  P H I L O L O G Y*](http://www.elegio.it/doc/pi/piph95.htm)

Regards

Comment: Nice...I hadn't seen this earlier!

Comment: @amWhy: I am always surprised by the weirdness one encounters at times. I just reread the account about an professor analyzing math terms, then using the analysis to write a bogus paper and it was accepted by a (non) reputable journal. I also knew a professor who used math to write poetry and some of it was actually very good!

Answer (score 3):

At the Feynman point:

Calculate perimeter: eightieth, ninetieth, hundredth: endlessly!

Comment: +1 funny. Here's the link: [Feynman point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_point)

Answer (score 3):

Of matrices becoming usually singular consider likeliness reasoning, given sufficient hugeness (unlike merely randomness), he said, so I do.

Solution: http://oeis.org/A048651/

Answer (score 2):

An ostrich, a platypus,
an elephant, a tapeworm,
in selfsame boat abide
cataclysm?

Answer (score 1):

Que j'aime à faire apprendre une nombre utile aux sages, immortel archimède, artiste ingènieux...

Answer (score 0):

I understand that if you recite Homer's Odyssey and Iliad, you repectively get $\frac{2e^2+3}{3π +1}$ and $2\sqrt{π} + 1$. Easy calculations then give you $π$ and $e$ making all other mnemonics superfluous.

Comment: How does this work? Can you give an example calculation using [Homer's Odyssey](http://wtso.net/movie/281-The_Simpsons_103_Homer039s_Odyssey.html)...

Comment: @draks... I'm afraid you'll have to take the Ancient Greek original.

Comment: D'oh, nuts! Hmm Donuts, but go ahead...

Comment: Citation needed?